# Create a local script that manipulates DOM elements in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scripting

I would like to make a script (that is ready on, or shortly after boot) that, when I surf to specific websites, it checks for certain DOM elements on the site and manipulates them.

Example: if there is a `<div id="foo">Bar</div>` somewhere on the page and I would like to change it to `<div id="bar">Foo</div>`.

How would I do this? I know I can do all this via developer tools, but I want this to be an automated process for certain sites I visit frequently.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Chrome extensions` might help! _Guess.._

Comment: Build yourself an extension for the browser you're using. Make the extension scan the page and change the elements as you want them.

Comment: If you don't want to bother with your own extension, I'd recommend Tampermonkey. It's available for a multitude of browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make Chrome extensions.
2. Make Javascript Bookmarklets.
3. Make your own iframe. and render a page in the iframe.

Comment: 3? Really? How would you modify the page through an iframe?